# How to refresh kendo grid base on additional paramer

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a customize Read function for kendo grid ....

```
 public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,
        RecordStatus? recoredStatus){ // code here }
```

now I want refresh my grid by using record status in kendo with jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function viewButtonClickHandler(e) {
        alert(e.Id)
        $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read(e.Id);
        $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

}

but how I send this additional parameter ( recordStatus )in read function !? can I do this !?

Comment: There are couple of problem in your question that make it ambiguous to answer , 1st you dont have given code how you declared your kendo grid . i have given answer based on mvc based grid . if this is not what you looking for edit your question and i will update the answer.ALSO what is type detail of this RecordStatus ? that is not built in type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are using Kendo MVC UI you can use the Data property for the Read method of DataSource . So the client side method **DataHandlerName** will execute while you are requesting for the read action, by using-

```
    $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
```

You can easily handle the client side script. Your Server Side code will be following for Kendo GRID,

```
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().ServerOperation(false).Read(r=> r.Action("ActionName","ControllerName").Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("DataHandlerName")))
```

And your client side code will be-

```
    <script> 
       function DataHandlerName() {
         //your code will goes here 

          var request={
                  id:1
                };
             return request ;
       }
   </script>
```

And Your Action Mehtod will be,

```
public ActionResult ActionName([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,int id){}
```

Comment: thanks , I solved the problem by using Html.Action , Partial view and jquery ajax ( I just refresh the grid in every call from scratch !!! ) .... probably my solution isn't good but my superiors put pressure on me with impossible deadlines and they don't care about quality of code , so I won't change it ... I don't have Kendo UI License and I can't use it for my personal projects ....

Answer (score 1):

***Using Purely java script this is how you can send params to read method***

```
$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.Read({id:e.Id});
$('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

On Server Side you need this.

```
public ActionResult Products_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,int id){}
```

If you are using MVC based grid telerik forum already has example on how to do use read to send extra parameters .

http://www.telerik.com/forums/pass-additional-parameters-to-read-ajax-datasource-method---mvc

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you just need this. And also please take a look to the link. It may can helps you.

```
function onSomeButtonClick(){
grid_.dataSource.read({q:"test"});
```

}

http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-refresh-a-grid-with-parameters-dc0f416ce08a

Comment: user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required.

Comment: @SeanCh I just read https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en. I did not make any changes on the original post. Could you please provide me more information about your comment?

Comment: Attribution + NoDerivatives  - not orginal post . please look into answers too