# Populating ASP.NET MVC Kendo Grid Via Ajax Call

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC Kendo Grid and I want to fill it via a jQuery Ajax Call. I used jQuery 'each' method to do it like this :

```
function FillRowsByRequest(reqRow) {
        var readDataUrl = '@Url.Action("GetGoodsByReq")';
        var targetGrid = $("#storeReceiptRowsGrid").data("kendoGrid");

        $.get(readDataUrl, { reqseq: reqRow }, function (d, t, j) {
            var counter = 0;
            targetGrid.cancelChanges();
            $(d).each(function (i, e) {
                targetGrid.dataSource.insert(counter++, {
                    GOOD_ID: e.GOOD_ID,
                    GOOD_CODE: e.GOOD_CODE,
                    GOOD_CODE_DESC: e.GOOD_CODE_DESC,
                    GOOD_DESC: e.GOOD_DESC
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

I can see my Kendo Grid that is filled with data ( not completely ) but the thing is that when I click on the Save button, it does not trigger the Save Action Method and consequently nothing is inserted in the table and Grid contains nothing after it is refreshed.

```
@(Html.Kendo()
    .Grid<Tpph.Models.STORE_RECEIPT_ROW>()
    .Name("storeReceiptRowsGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.GOOD_ID).Title("Good ID").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "goodid" }).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(o => o.GOOD_CODE).Title("Good Code").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "goodcode" }).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.GOOD_CODE_DESC).Title("Good Code Desc").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "goodcodedesc" }).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.GOOD_DESC).Title("Good Desc").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "gooddesc" }).Width(155);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Create().Text("New Row").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-primary", style = "background-color: #e6ffe6; border-color: #10c4b2; min-width: 100px; color: black;" });
        toolbar.Save().Text("Save").SaveText("Save").CancelText("Cancel").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-primary", style = "background-color: #e6ffe6; border-color: #10c4b2; min-width: 100px; color: black;" });
    })
    .ColumnMenu()
    .Selectable(s => s.Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
    .Sortable()
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Delete?"))
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Pageable(p => p.Refresh(true))
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
         .Ajax()
         .Events(ev => ev.RequestEnd("storeReceiptRowsGridOnRequestEnd"))
         .Batch(true)
         .ServerOperation(true)
         .Model(model =>
         {
             model.Id(p => p.GOOD_ID);
         })
         .Read(read => read.Action("StoreReceiptRowsRead", "StorageForms"))
         .Update(u => u.Action("StoreReceiptRowsEdit", "StorageForms"))
         .Create(c => c.Action("StoreReceiptRowsCreate", "StorageForms"))
         .Destroy(de => de.Action("StoreReceiptRowsDestory", "StorageForms")))
    .Events(ev =>
    {
        ev.DataBound("storeReceiptRowsGridOnBound");
    })
    )
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Suppose that by Ajax call, I want to fill these fields and then when I click on the Save button, I want it to save the populated data. If I type in the fields manually, it works but when I populate the grid via jQuery Ajax call, it does not trigger the Save Action Method.

Comment: Please add the ajaxcall in your above code.

Comment: You shouldn't need an AJAX call in your JS if you have hooked up the dataSource `.Create` event correctly. Post your controller function `StoreReceiptRowsCreate`.

Comment: @TechVision : Well I am not sure whether my JavaScript Code is correct or not. That is why I asked the question. By the way, I added it in the question too.

Comment: for binding you can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789688/how-to-refresh-kendo-grid-base-on-additional-paramer/41802689#41802689

Comment: @TechVision : You got it wrong. I do not want to bind. I want to fill the rows of my grid via the Data sent back from the Ajax Call. These data are there to show the user the Rows that are going to be inserted into the table ( JUST FOR PREVIEW ). So the user can modify them and finally after clicking the Save button, the rows will be inserted into the table. I can show the data to the user. but when I click on the Save button, the client preview of data do not sent to the Action Method and the grid becomes empty.

Comment: @SeanCh The problem is not related to the Action Methods. If you read the question carefully, I said IT DOES NOT TRIGGER ANY ACTION METHOD AT ALL WHICH MEAN IT DOES NOT GO TO THE CONTROLLER AT ALL.

Comment: @Ali - well in that case you should be smart enough to figure out the actual problem also.thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of struggling with this issue, I finally found out that the Kendo Grid triggers the CRUD Action Methods only when the "dirty" attribute of a row is set to true. ( dirty flag is a tiny little red triangle which appears in the corner of a cell when you edit that cell ). So the solution to this issue is setting dirty flag of each row to true like this :

```
.set("dirty", true);
```

So my final JavaScript Code is like this :

```
function FillRowsByRequest(reqRow) {
        var readDataUrl = '@Url.Action("GetGoodsByReq")';
        var targetGrid = $("#storeReceiptRowsGrid").data("kendoGrid");

        $.get(readDataUrl, { reqseq: reqRow }, function (d, t, j) {
            var counter = 0;
            targetGrid.cancelChanges();
            $(d).each(function (i, e) {
                targetGrid.dataSource.insert(counter++, {
                    GOOD_ID: e.GOOD_ID,
                    GOOD_CODE: e.GOOD_CODE,
                    GOOD_CODE_DESC: e.GOOD_CODE_DESC,
                    GOOD_DESC: e.GOOD_DESC
                }).set("dirty", true);
            });
        });
    }
```